# How do I Use Reflection API getParameters in Android API level 25 and Below?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I am currently building an in-app logger utility for Android that uses the Reflection API to log basic data about the called class/method/parameters.

`Method.getParameters()` is the call to retrieve an array of parameters for the given method, *but this method only works on Android API level 26+*. Does anyone know of a workaround that would let me use `getParameters()` on API level 25 or below?

Alternatively, if there is a decent workaround for this, that would work too! Thanks in advance! Here is the method I will be updating once I have a fix/workaround in place:

```
private Parameter[] _retrieveParametersForMethod( Method method ) {

    Parameter[] methodParameters;

    // getParameters() only works on API level 26+ (Oreo)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        return methodParameters = method.getParameters();
    } else
        return null;    // TODO: Find a workaround for pre-API level 26

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will work for you, but I got a lot of mileage out of apache beanutils:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/

Comment: I see that this wraps the Java Reflection API - have you had any trouble getting the method parameters on an Android device lower than 26? My concern is that I will still run into this limitation since the restriction is set within the Reflection API